# Number of fields in pasted data doesn't match the columns in the table

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5, mysql-workbench

## Situation

I had a table with 8 columns, then I need 2 more fields :

- company_wieght
- server_type_weight

So I run a migration to add those fields, and now I have 10 columns.

[image]

I got 0 data in there right now.

---

## I want

to copy/paste all the data from my staging server back to my local. I keep get a error :

[image]

How do I solve this problem ?

Is there a way to force paste rows,and leave the other 2 rows as NULL/blank ? With that I can add data to them later via migration.

I'm a little stuck now on that.

Comment: You can create a console command to copy your data.  See `artisan make:console`. Or maybe you can run the migration after you copy the data when the number of columns is still 8.

Comment: Make sure you run the migration on both the staging database and your local database.

Comment: Yeah, I am getting this bogus error too. I am definitely pasting the correct number of columns. Nearly every column has some blank cells, however, which may be throwing the program off. I tried filling in the blank spaces with `\N` (null) instead, but it hasn't helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems there are several aspects mixed in here. For MySQL Workbench: source and target column count in a copy/paste action must be the same, no way around it. However, I wouldn't copy over data with copy/paste unless it's really not much and not needed many times. Instead I'd export the existing data to a csv file, load that in a spreadsheet (e.g. in Open Office) and add 2 dummy columns. Export that to csv again and import in MySQL Workbench.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it:

1. Make sure that your new columns are nullable in migration

   ```
   $table->integer('company_weight')->nullable(); // make sure you use nullable()
   $table->integer('server_type_weight')->nullable();
   ```
2. Dump the table data on your staging server

   ```
   $ mysqldump -u<username> -p --no-create-info --compact --skip-comments \
   --complete-insert <database> <table> > /path/to/file.sql
   ```
3. Download resulting file.sql to your local machine
4. Import data to your local database

   ```
   $ mysql -u<username> -p <database> < /path/to/file.sql
   ```